# Loading images / links with jQuery & AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I've been having trouble getting my images to show on the page after they have fully loaded through ajax. I did some research and solved the problem like this:

```
var img = $('<img id="img-photo-1" />').attr('src', data+'.png').load(function(){
                $("#jacket").html(img);
            });
```

Which is great, but I also want to wrap the image with a link also returned from AJAX so I tried this:

```
 img1 = $('<img id="img-photo-1 />').attr('src', data).load(function(){ 
           $("div#photo1").html('<a class="shadowbox" id="link-photo-1" href="'+data+'">'+img1+'</a>');
        });
```

But this shows the image as an object and doesn't render as an image. Any ideas on how to fix this, I'm sure it can be done with a similar approach, cheers

Comment: `.load()` expects a url parameter.  I'm not sure how your first code snippet works.  Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @fehays: There are 2 load methods.  [One](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is shorthand for `$.ajax`, [the other](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is shorthand for `.bind('onload')`.  Which one is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Comment: @Rocket, i stand corrected.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `img1` is a jQuery object, you can't use it like a string.  Try using `append` to add it to the DOM.

```
img1 = $('<img id="img-photo-1 />').attr('src', data).load(function(){ 
    var $html = $('<a class="shadowbox" id="link-photo-1" href="'+data+'" />');
    $html.append(img1);
    $("div#photo1").empty().append($html); // I used empty(), because html() would replace anything inside the div
});
```

Comment: Aha... great answer. I knew it was a matter of getting the logic right. Thanks Rocket!

Answer (score 0):

Your `img1` var is a jquery element.  So perhaps what you need is to return `img1.html()` to concatenate the anchor tag string you are building:

```
img1 = $('<img id="img-photo-1 />').attr('src', data).load(function(){ 
           $("div#photo1").html('<a class="shadowbox" id="link-photo-1" href="'+data+'">'+img1.html()+'</a>');
        });
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  `.html()` gets the `innerHTML`, but for this to work, he'd need the `outerHTML`.

Comment: Correct, thanks for the suggestions guys but still no luck. Ill keep trying. As fehays said, using .load in this way is really like .bind('onload') I want the image to fully load before it displays, while a loader gif is displayed. It works fine I'm just having problems getting a link around it also

Comment: Apologies Rocket, as Rocket said regarding .load()